# почему не работает?

Tags: c#

> Даны два точечных заряда `q1` и `q2`, расположенные на расстоянии `d`
>   друг от друга. Написать программу, вычисляющую силу их взаимного притяжения. Коэффициент пропорциональности `k = 1/4πϵ0`, где `ϵ0` ≈ 8,85×10<sup>−12</sup> Фм.
>
> Ответ вывести в виде: «Сила притяжения между зарядами `q1` Кл и `q2` Кл, находящихся на расстоянии `d` м, равна `F` Н.». Вместо буквенных обозначений должны стоять конкретные числа с точностью до 2-го знака после запятой. Перед запросом ввода с клавиатуры выводить подсказку.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            double q1, q2, d, k, F;

        Console.WriteLine("Вычисление силы взаимного притяженияю. Введите q1,q2 и d (расстояние между ними) : ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Вместо буквенных обозначений должны стоять конкретные числа с точностью до 2-го знака после запятой. Введите q1 : ");
            q1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите q2 : ");
            q2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Введите d(расстояние между ними) : ");
            d = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

            k = 1 / 4 * 8.85 * 10^(-12);
            F = k * q1 * q2 / d;
            Console.WriteLine("" + F);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Я автор задачника, из которого взята эта задача и, по-видимому, преподаватель автора вопроса. У меня к нему меня большая просьба — решайте задачи самостоятельно!

Answer (score 4):

> 10^(-12)

Потому что это xor. Попробуй 1e-12.

> k = 1 / 4 * 8.85 * 10^(-12);

А ещё, возможно, ты где-то скобки потерял. Внимательнее, что именно там знаменатель.

> 4πϵ<sub>0</sub>

А куда π делось в программе?

Comment: Я бы еще сделал `k = 1E+12 / (4 * 8.85);` должно получится точнее

Comment: @Mirdin Там в формуле число `8.85e-12`, только я не пойму, в числителе или в знаменателе... UPDATE: Перечитал. В чём идея переноса в числитель из знаменателя? Почему точнее?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%9A%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0](`4πϵ0`целиком в знаменателе). Учитывая что, `8.85E-12 = 8.85 / 1E+12` 1E+12 можно перенести вверх

Comment: @Mirdin, да, я уже поправил свой комментарий, когда понял, что в нём плюс, а не минус. А можно пояснить, почему так будет точнее? Умножение на 4 бесплатное, одна константа в знаменателе смотрится лучше, чем две неточные, разве нет?

Comment: @Qwerty, там двенадцать нулей после запятой, `double` будет работать на пределе точности. А если перенесем вверх то только 2-3 знака после запятой, следовательно будет меньше погрешности

Comment: @Qwerty, уточню, я не уверен, что именно в данном случае, будет точнее. Это скорее сработает в более сложных выражениях, где трубуется более чем 2 знака после запятой, а умножения и деления двигают их туда и обратно.

Comment: @Mirdin у double есть лимит точности мантиссы, а не общий лимит точности. в нем число представляется как (мантисса 1, экспонента -12), только в двоичной форме. а разницы между (1, -12) и (1, 12) никакой нет.

Comment: @PashaPash, да уже понял.. , дурная привычка сокращать степени :).

Comment: @PashaPash, вообще-то 1e12 представимо точно, а 1e-12 - нет.

Comment: @Qwertiy да, я просто напомнил что погрешность там не в знаках после запятой, а в значащих цифрах. 8.85 не представимо точно, так что без разницы.

Comment: @Qwertiy я не знаю что такое xor

Comment: @2212, но гугл знает. Даже сводку выводит.